# MySQL client to Manage/Add/Delete Rows in Nested Set Tables

Tags: gui, mysql

I am looking for a MySQL client such as [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/) or [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) that can manage/add/delete rows in nested set tables.

To be more precise I am looking for client that will automatically rebuild the lft,rgt and level columns commonly used in nested set tables - typically based on a parent_id column - either after each insert or on demand.

Comment: please read [*What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?*](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336) and add some additional information like *on which OS should it run?*, *what budget do you have?*, *is F(L)OSS required?*, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can manage, add, delete rows using *EMS SQL Manager for MySQL*. For other purposes you asked please visit: [Specifying master level using EMS SQL Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/manager/documentation/hs3960.html)

Here's some of its features

**Advanced data manipulation tools**

- View, edit, search, group, sort, filter any data stored in registered
  database
- Powerful BLOB viewer/editor with several types of viewing BLOB data
- Master-detail view to work with two linked tables at the same time
- Table and card views to see data the way you like
- Support of queries returning Multiple Result sets
- Ability to copy and paste selected records
- Exporting data to SQL script as INSERT statement

Hope this helps.